# Is there a (linear) functional $f\in (C[-1,1])^*$ such that $f$ maps even continuous function to $0$ and odd continuous function to its infinite norm

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a (linear) functional $f\in (C[-1,1])^*$ such that for any even function $g$ in $c[-1,1]$, $f(g)=0$, and for any odd fucntion  $h$ in $c[-1,1]$,  $f(h)=||h||_\infty$?

Comment: You call a function $g \in C([0,1])$ even or odd iff ...? If with $h$ also $-h$ is odd, then such an $f$ cannot be linear.

Comment: Even function is even symmetric w.r.t middle point of domain, To avoid $\frac{1}{2}$, I change the space.

Comment: But I still suspect that f is not linear on odd functions.

Comment: Do you mean "linear functional?" Because there are non-linear functionals.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, Although I changed the problem, but I think there non-linear functionals, we don't consider them often.

Comment: @Shine Well, we use them all the time we we use norms, and the fact that a norm here is referenced means we might be talking non-linear. In particular, all linear functions that are not everywhere zero take negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $h$ odd, then so is $-h$. So if such functional $f$ existed, then we would have
$$
f(h)=\|h\|_\infty=\|-h\|_\infty=f(-h),
$$
which would imply that $\|h\|_\infty=0$, for every odd function $h$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, $f$ can't be linear on the collection of odd functions.

Comment: Do you think we can find such $f$ is we only demand that for one given odd function $h_0$,  $f(h_0)=||h_0||_\infty$ and $f$ maps even function to $o$？

Answer (score 2):

The question didn't originally  ask for a linear functional, merely a functional.

If $g\in C([-1,1])$ then define:

$$f(g)=\sup_{x\in[-1,1]} \left|\frac{g(x)-g(-x)}{2}\right|$$

is such a continuous but non-linear functional.

Comment: Yes, it Looks good.